# Why does US currency have a 25 cent piece and a 20 dollar bill instead of a 20 cent piece or 25 dollar bill?

Tags: united-states, currency

Why does US currency have a 25 cent piece instead of a 20 cent piece?  Why is there a 20 dollar bill instead of a 25 dollar bill?  Why aren't both denominations the same, 20 or 25 for both the dollars and cents?

Comment: Wikipedia article on the quarter has your answer, albeit unsourced: "A quarter, short for quarter dollar, is a U.S. coin worth 25 cents, one-fourth of a dollar. It has been produced since 1796. The choice of 1⁄4 as a denomination—as opposed to the 1⁄5 more common elsewhere—originated with the practice of dividing Spanish milled dollars into eight wedge-shaped segments. At one time "two bits" (that is, two "pieces of eight") was a common nickname for a quarter."

Comment: Interesting question. Never even considered how odd it is!

Comment: For a brief time there was a 20 cent piece https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-cent_piece_(United_States_coin)

Comment: In the UK, the denominations follow a very obvious pattern: 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, £1, £2, £5 and so on.  There was a survey recently (perhaps someone can find a link) where British people were asked which new coin they'd most like to have and which current coin was the last useful.  The results: the least useful current coin was the 2p coin, and the most useful new coin to have would be a 25p coin!

Comment: In the USSR, the coins were 1k,2k,3k,5k,10k,15k,20k,50k,1r; paper money was 1r,3r,5r,10r,25r (i.e., there was a 20k _coin_ and a 25r _note_).

Comment: Should perhaps be noted that most of the paper money denominations were coins before they were paper.  Curiously, the US once minted a $2.50 "Quarter Eagle" gold coin, as well as 3 cent and $3 coins: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:United_States_gold_coins  I would guess that the denominations people found inconvenient simply fell out of use, just as today it's rare to see half dollar or dollar coins, or the $2 bill.

Comment: @JohnGowers A 25p coin would actually be harmful, unless we got rid of the 20p. If every coin is worth at least twice as much as the previous one, you can give change in the fewest number of coins simply by repeatedly giving the biggest coin that doesn't go over the target (e.g., 41p = 20+20+1). But if you don't maintain this at-least-doubling property, it no longer works (e.g., 41p becomes 25+10+5+1, but 20+20+1 is fewer coins).

Comment: @jamesqf There were also half-eagle and eagle coins. People always say that it's the vending machine industry that most objects to dollar coins replacing bills. Obviously, any change would be expensive for them, even though only having to handle coins would be much cheaper in the long run. Ironically, the only time I've ever received dollar coins in change was... from a vending machine.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The TRAX tram machines in Salt Lake City were giving out dozens of dollar coins in change at a time when I was last there.  It made me think that perhaps they were starting to supplant bills in the US.

Comment: @David Richerby: Well, dollar coins - silver dollars - have been around for a long time.  IIRC, they (and half dollars) were pretty common up to the 1970s.  It's the smaller Anthony & Sacagawea dollars that have been unpopular.  The switch from actual silver coins to base metal in the 1960s helped make them unpopular.

Comment: @David Richerby: OTOH, once you have a working automatic bill reader, it's fairly trivial to modify it to read any denomination.  For instance, a local convenience store used to have gas pumps with bill readers that'd take anything up to $20.  Very convenient (especially since the cash price was less than credit).  I still don't know why they eliminated them.

Comment: Are you familiar with the 'farthing' in English coinage?

Comment: @twosheds - " At one time "two bits" (that is, two "pieces of eight") was a common nickname for a quarter."  - Heh, my father still uses the term 'two bits' in standard conversation today to refer to a quarter.  Rural Canada has oddly kept that term going.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because Americans were used to dealing in quarters at the time the denomination was chosen. During the colonial period, a common unit of currency was **[one eighths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_(money)) of a [Spanish *real de a ocho*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_dollar)**. Since each of these Spanish dollars were worth **eight** [Spanish *reales*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_real) it was habitual to divide the eight-real coin into 12.5% wedges known as [*bits*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_(money)). Two of these were therefore equivalent to 25% of the Spanish  dollar, i.e. 25 cents.

When the nascent United States adopted its own currency standard, the original [one dollar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar) was based on the aforementioned Spanish dollar. The customary unit of *two bits* of the Spanish dollar thus became [*25 cents*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter_(United_States_coin)) of the equivalent United States dollar.

> In 1793, Congress adopted decimal coinage  - 100 cents to the dollar - to replace the eights into which Spanish dollars were divided. Nevertheless, old habits died hard. Congress also instructed the U.S,. Mint to coin quarter dollars. Quarters made no sense decimally, but they reflected the partition of a Spanish dollar into eight *reales*.
>
> **<sub>- Conlin, Joseph. *The American Past: A Survey of American History, Volume II: Since 1865*. Cengage Learning, 2013.</sub>**

Comment: Could you extend your answer for the 2nd OP's question? Why is then 20 dollar note?

Comment: I think the above answers both: people were used to a quarter of something, but there was nothing such a _25-times-of_.

Comment: @Voitcus additionally, '25' is somewhat the exception ('20' being usually preferred because it makes calculating how much exchange the clerk has to return easier, specially at a time when there were no electronic calculators).

Comment: "Quarters made no sense decimal" I don't really buy the idea that quarters make less sense than fifths. I guess it's very slightly easier to make change with 20c rather than 25c but, honestly, I can't say I've ever had a problem with the speed with which American shop assistants make change.

Comment: That sentence is clearly talking about sense *in terms of the **decimal** system*, i.e. the system using the *number **ten** as its base*. It is not saying making change is harder or slower with quarters.

Comment: The Pound Sterling would also have been a secondary well-known currency and earlier colonial currencies had been modelled on it. With the pre-decimal penny the Pound was also easily divisible by 8 with there being 8 Half-Crowns (2/ 6d) in each Pound.

Comment: As a curiosity, in Spain before Euro was a 25 pesetas coin but no 20 pesetas coin. Now with Euro we have 20c but not 25c.

Comment: @MarioLevrero I think those were leftovers from before the stadardization of the peseta in the XIX. More concisely, the "duro" were 20 "reals" and equivalent (after standardization) to 5 pesetas, the "cinco (five) duros" would have been 100 reals. Note that for higher (and more modern) denominations, we ended with 200 pesetas coins and 2000 pesetas notes.

Comment: Excellent answer. As an interesting side note, the word "dollar" does not derive from Spanish, but from the German Thaler (today spelled Taler). At the time, most of the various states that made up Germany had their own currencies. Many regions were centered around valleys (Tal/formerly Thal in German), and thus many cities and regions have Tal in their name. Coins from such regions were often called Taler. The specific one the dollar is supposedly named after came from Johannistal, Bohemia (which today isn't even in Germany any more).

Comment: @SJuan76: Historically, sales clerks **never** performed subtraction; rather they *counted up* from the price to the amount tendered in payment as they created the correct amount of change. With this methodology it makes little, if any, difference whether the intermediate coin is 20 cents or 25.  It is a shame that this practice is no longer taught to retail clerks.

Comment: Additionally, British currency of the time already contained the [*Crown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_(British_coin)) as a coin, worth 5 shillings and making it a 1/4 Pound coin.

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought it was because of best way to reduce number of coins needed before I read Semaphore's answer.

I thought it was designed this way due to efficiency: 
for example at all values between 0 and 1 dollar that ends in 0 or 5

5 cent = 1 coin

10 cent = 1 coin

15 cent = 2 coins

**20 cent = 2 coins (1 coin if using 5/10/20)**

25 cent = 1 coin (2 coins if using 5/10/20)

30 cent = 2 coins

35 cent = 2 coins (3 coins if using 5/10/20)

**40 cent = 3 coins (2 coins if using 5/10/20)**

45 cent = 3 coins

50 cent = 2 coins (3 coins if using 5/10/20)

55 cent = 3 coins (4 coins if using 5/10/20)

60 cent = 3 coins

65 cent = 4 coins

70 cent = 4 coins

75 cent = 3 coins (5 coins if using 5/10/20)

80 cent = 4 coins

85 cent = 4 coins (5 coins if using 5/10/20)

90 cent = 5 coins

95 cent = 5 coins (6 coins if using 5/10/20)

1 dollar = 4 coins (5 coins if using 5/10/20)

*There are only 2 occasions that 5/10/20 uses less coins than 5/10/25*

Comment: This is kind of cheating, since most systems that use a 20 coin also have a 50.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It doesn't do that at all! 5/10/20/50 beats 5/10/25 for 11 different change values (three of them by a two-coin margin); 5/10/25 only wins for two (25 and 35, each by one coin). The irony is that 5/10/25/50 and 5/10/20/50 are equally good -- the US has a 50c coin but you never see them in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer basically boils down to attrition.  Over the years, the US has minted many denominations of coins, ranging from the half cent piece up to the $50 Half-Union coin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_of_the_United_States_dollar#Obsolete_coins

Most of them have fallen out of use for various reasons, mostly because having many denominations proved inconvenient and/or confusing.  The US did mint a 20 cent piece for a few years, but it was unpopular because it was easily confused with a quarter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-cent_piece_(United_States_coin)  The same was true of the short-lived Susan B. Anthony dollar coin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_coin_(United_States)#Susan_B._Anthony_dollar_(1979%E2%80%931981;_1999) which I suspect (along with the inconvenience of having two $1 coins of very different sizes) contributed to the current unpopularity of the dollar coin.  (Gold coins are obviously a special case, thanks to FDR &c.)

I'd guess that the use of cash registers also played a part, as they can easily fit only so many pockets for coins.  Perhaps that also caused the virtual abandonment of the $2 bill, and is contributing to the decline I've seen in the use of the $10 bill.  (My grocery store only gives out $5 bills in change, and any $10s you give them are tucked underneath the tray.)